# Not able to remove specific bytes from buffer using memcpy

Tags: c, memory

I m not able to truncate the buffer from the size what I want. I'm bit perplexed why I get wrong results? Even though my usage of memcpy() is right. I read the man page also. I'm doing something wrong here?

---

**What I want to achieve:**

```
Buff: 00 83 00 00 16 0a 44 00 00 00 00 bd 0e 8a 0c 61 01 13 51 24 ad 9a 0b 1c 0e ff ff 00
```

Copy the bytes which start from bd, that means 12th bytes till the end-

**Desired Output should be:**

`bd 0e 8a 0c 61 01 13 51 24 ad 9a 0b 1c 0e ff ff 00`

**This is my code:**
I'm receiving the response from serial device and I need chop some bytes.

```
void rx_dev(transport, int addr, const void *buf, unsigned count) {
    uint8_t s[1024];
    uint8_t *p;

    memset (s, 0, sizeof(s));
    // This below function does only the hex parsing.
    hex_parse(s, sizeof(s), buf, count);
    printf("* %02x %s\n", addr, s);

    printf("Count: %zu\n", count);
    p = s;

    printf("p* %s\n", p);

    // I'm doing this check to avoid something greater than 14.
    if (count > 14) {
        memcpy(p, s+11, count-11);
        printf("*Trim:%s\n", p);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Added the more details

```
int hex_parse(char *out, unsigned size, const void *buf, unsigned count)
{
    const uint8_t *p = buf;
    unsigned i;
    int n = 0;

    if (count)
    {
        if (n + 2 < size)
        {
            out[n+0] = hexchars[(p[0] >> 4) & 15];
            out[n+1] = hexchars[p[0] & 15];
        }
        n += 2;
    }

    for (i = 1; i < count; i++) {
        if (n + 3 < size)
        {
            out[n+0] = ' ';
            out[n+1] = hexchars[(p[i] >> 4) & 15];
            out[n+2] = hexchars[p[i] & 15];
        }
        n += 3;
    }

    if (n < size)
        out[n] = '\0';
    else if (size)
        out[size-1] = '\0';

    return n;
}
```

**My ouutput:**

```
* 01 00 83 00 00 16 0a 44 00 00 00 00 bd 0e 8a 0c 61 01 13 51 24 ad 9a 0b 1c 0e ff ff 00

p* 00 83 00 00 16 0a 44 00 00 00 00 bd 0e 8a 0c 61 01 13 51 24 ad 9a 0b 1c 0e ff ff 00
```

Here I don't get the correct output, why is it prinitng 28bytes, this is not my desired result I wanted?

```
Trim: 16 0a 44 00 00 0 44 00 00 00 00 bd 0e 8a 0c 61 01 13 51 24 ad 9a 0b 1c 0e ff ff 00
```

Comment: I think we need to see `hex_parse` to understand this fully.  However, if you are converting the buffer to a hex string why are you trimming the hex string and not the buffer first.

Comment: @mttrb I added the hex_parse function implementation also.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `memmove` , as in `memcpy` the target and the source must not overlap each other, while in memmove it does not matter.  So you can do

```
 int offset = 11,size = 28;
 memmove(buf, buf+off, size - off);
```

Comment: @alinsor , I used memove, eventhough that didnt help. Buf is void pointer, here I m adding +11 to void pointer. I doesn't seems to move the bytes from the specific buffer. It just prints the junk value.

Comment: memmove must work.  You should now use magic numbers inside the code but I used them just to provide an example of use.

Answer (score 2):

The source and destination in your `memcpy` call overlap. From the standard:

> If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior
>   is undefined.

The standard function `memmove` is like `memcpy` but defined for overlapping objects, use that instead.

Comment: how to avoid the overlap, is it possible i can't have another pointer as destination?

Comment: @DanglingPointer You can copy to a different buffer.

Comment: I tried to copy into the different buffer, I just get garbage value.         `memmove(rx, buf+11, count-11);` and `rx is uint8_t rx[1024]; ` Seems I doing some mistake here. Would be nice if you tell me why? Here buf is void pointer.

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling `memcpy`, you're not copying the bytes from the buffer. You're copying the "hex_parsed" string. As that format uses 3 characters per byte (2 digits and a space), chopping 11 characters is chopping about 4 bytes.

Comment: thanks for pointing out. Your correct, formated uses 3 characters per byte. In my case, i want to copy from 12th byte then 11*3 = 33. But count gives me 28, I want to print only till end.

Comment: @DanglingPointer `count` has the same problem. It counts the bytes in the buffer, not the characters in the `hex_parsed`string.

Comment: I used like this  `memmove(rx, buf+11, count-11);` in which rx is uint8_t rx[1024]; but I dont get the correct answer even after using memmove.

Comment: @DanglingPointer: Your code has multiple issues (mixing bytes and characters, overlapping source and destination) and you need to fix all of them

Comment: thanks for pointing out. Beacuse thats what my impression is code has multiple issue,  i m not having correct src that is why my destination get wrong value. I will figure it out.